# Can you send a postcard somewhere at Cancun Airport (CUN)?

Tags: airports, mail, cancun, cun

Is it possible to send a (stamped) postcard somewhere within Cancun International Airport (CUN)?

If so, where in the airport can I find a post office or mailbox?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: None of my postcards ex-Mexico has ever reached destination.  Indeed my Mexican friends avoid national mail service as a matter of course.  Good luck if you can find a mailbox.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero spot on

Comment: In the interests of showing research effort, [I can't see anything on the airport website](https://www.cancunairport.com/) - by the level of detail it looks like it should list any post office if there was one, although mailboxes maybe not.

Comment: I recently purchased international stamps and sent 10 post cards from this nearby post office box on 2.28.23. However, the mail box was stuffed full. I hope this mail will reach its intended destinations soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can say that there was at least one post office box in April 2014, according to [Google](https://www.google.com/maps/@21.0398692,-86.8739539,2a,90y,347.45h,66.59t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sOFMUaVTjbIwfqc7_VzQ_hw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I sadly didn't have time to go all the way into Terminal 2, but still good to know for the next time, I'm there.

Answer (score 3):

We found a mail box in the Cancun airport Terminal 4 near the convenience store. It was near check in location E (61-80).